# Conditional EventHandling

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I believe I have a design question and I hope to get your input.  I made a small program to illustrate my question.  Basically, my program consists of a radio system that gets heard on every room in the building.  The sound is conditional on the receiving end, depending if the room registers itself to the radio system.

My problem is that the message sent is triggered on every room, even if the room is not registered.   I would prefer to do the condition before the message gets sent out, rather then on the receiving end.  By doing this, I could save myself unnecessary traffic.  Can anyone give me an idea or the correct way to resolve this type of situation?

Just for the record, I would prefer not to have multiple event handlers in the radio, since I don't know how many rooms there will be.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Radio
{
#region Speakers
public interface ISound
{
    string sound { get; set; }
}
public abstract class RoomSpeaker : ISound
{
    public string sound { get; set; }
}
public class Room1Speaker : RoomSpeaker
{
}
public class Room2Speaker : RoomSpeaker
{
}
public class BuildingSpeaker : RoomSpeaker
{
}
#endregion
#region Rooms
public abstract class Room
{
    public Radio radioPlayer;
    public string name;
    public HashSet<Type> registeredSpeakers = new HashSet<Type>();

    public virtual void RoomPlayer(string lyrics)
    {
        registeredSpeakers.Add(typeof(BuildingSpeaker));
        Console.WriteLine(lyrics);
    }
}
public class Room1 : Room
{
    public Room1(Radio radioPlayer)
    {
        this.radioPlayer = radioPlayer;
        name = "Room1";
        registeredSpeakers.Add(typeof(Room1Speaker));
        radioPlayer.onRadio += radioPlayer_onRadio;
    }

    // This is what I don't think I like.  It will only do something if it's registered. That's fine.
    // But on any radio message out, this room will get called regardless.  Should I NOT be doing this? Should I go back to
    // making an eventHandler for every room? rather then having one even handler for all the rooms and have a condition on the receiving end.

    void radioPlayer_onRadio(object sender, ISound e)
    {
        if (registeredSpeakers.Contains(e.GetType()))
            RoomPlayer(name + e.sound);
    }
}
public class Room2 : Room
{
    public Room2(Radio radioPlayer)
    {
        this.radioPlayer = radioPlayer;
        name = "Room2";
        registeredSpeakers.Add(typeof(Room2Speaker));
        radioPlayer.onRadio += radioPlayer_onRadio;
    }

    void radioPlayer_onRadio(object sender, ISound e)
    {
        // same problem as in Room1. 
        if (registeredSpeakers.Contains(e.GetType()))
            RoomPlayer(name + e.sound);
    }
}
#endregion

public class Radio
{
    public event EventHandler<ISound> onRadio;

    public void PlayRoom1()
    {
        onRadio(this, new Room1Speaker() { sound = "Test" });
    }
    public void PlayRoom2()
    {
        onRadio(this, new Room2Speaker() { sound = "Test" });
    }
    public void PlayAllRooms()
    {
        onRadio(this, new BuildingSpeaker() { sound = "Test All Rooms" });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var radio = new Radio();
        var room1 = new Room1(radio);
        var room2 = new Room2(radio);

        radio.PlayRoom1();
        radio.PlayRoom2();
        radio.PlayAllRooms();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have some pretty core design issues to work out.  For starters, your radio shouldn't know about specific rooms.  The radio should be able to work just fine *no matter what room you put it in*.  Of course, how you should go about designing this correctly is going to depend on what your actual requirements are, and we don't know what your requirements are.

Comment: radioPlayer.onRadio += radioPlayer_onRadio; this is basically registering for radio sound. Don't register if you don't want to hear radio. The eventhandling mechanism is basically an event producer consumer pattern.

Comment: I'm looking to have room N listen to only messages meant for it's room.  My way of resolving this is to do a condition on the receiving end.  
All the rooms must register, but I want to avoid the unnecessary traffic.

Comment: Servy: the requirement for this example program is simple.  All I want is for that room to listen to messages intended for it.  I wanted to keep it simple in order to get a clear answer.

Comment: @MIJ1974 That's *not* actually a clear definition of requirements.

Comment: The whole point of the event registration mechanism is that the producer does not know the details of the subscribers. Make up your mind if you want a generic event for everyone,say for the radio not matter which channel, or a specific event for say each radio channel. Both designs will work and have its pros and cons.

Comment: What I was looking for was a this.  Is this pattern incorrect?  I don't understand why Servy and Your comments sound as if this pattern is logically wrong.  I'm curious and want to understand.  I am not looking to build animosity between comrades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, what you're looking at is the publish-subscribe pattern (AKA eventbus). In eventbus pattern, you have a class that registers listeners and sends messages. Listeners tell the event bus "I'm listening for an event X". When the eventbus "sends" event X it consults its list of listeners for that event and if they are registered, executes the method that the listener told it to execute.

```cs
public class EventBus
{
    private Dictionary<Type, List<Action<IEvent>>> actions = new Dictionary<Type, List<Action<IEvent>>>();

    public void Listen<T>(Action<IEvent> callback) where T : IEvent
    {
        if (!actions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            actions.Add(typeof(T), new List<Action<IEvent>>());
        }

        actions[typeof(T)].Add(callback);
    }

    public void ClearCallbacks<T>() where T : IEvent
    {
        actions[typeof (T)] = null;
    }

    public void Send<T>(T @event) where T : IEvent
    {
        if (!actions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var action in actions[typeof(T)])
        {
            action(@event);
        }
    }
}

public interface IEvent
{
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main () {
    var eventBus = new EventBus();

    var aRoom = new NoisyRoom(eventBus);
    var bRoom = new NoisyRoom(eventBus);
    var cRoom = new NoisyRoom(eventBus);
    var dRoom = new QuietRoom(eventBus);

    eventBus.Send(new NoisyEvent()); //sends to a,b,c room
}

public class EasyListeningEvent : IEvent
{
}
public class QuietRoom
{
    public QuietRoom(EventBus eventBus)
    {
        eventBus.Listen<EasyListeningEvent>(BringTheNaps);
    }

    private void BringTheNaps(IEvent @event)
    {
        //its been brought!
    }
}

class NoisyEvent : IEvent
{
}
public class NoisyRoom
{
    public NoisyRoom(EventBus eventBus)
    {
        eventBus.Listen<NoisyEvent>(BringTheNoise);
    }

    private void BringTheNoise(IEvent @event)
    {
        //its been brought!
    }
}
```

Comment: In this context, events are related to the eventbus pattern. I'm not familiar with the 'event' in c# that you are talking about.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Wow I haven't seen `event` used since I last opened a forms project! I'd forgotten about them. I used IEvent here because it's the EventBus pattern. It's an easy F2 rename if anyone finds it confusing.

Comment: This was perfect for me.   Exactly what I was looking for.  Only the Subscribers get triggered,   This was pretty badass... Thanks!    I implemented your solution to my example program.  Pretty damn sweet (can you tell I'm exited?)

Comment: Why where you down-voted?  As per your explanation, this i s a legitimate design pattern, and this is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: Hah well I'm glad I could help! I'm not sure about the downvote, possibly someone got mad I beat them to the post :)

Comment: @CBauer events are applicable for non forms applications too you know. They are the event consumer producer system that is inherently applicable in NET.

Comment: Sure Phil, I'm just not familiar with event to rewrite this to make use of the type instead of my interface. If I posted it to code review would you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Try something a little more like this:

Edit: Note that this is just a start in the right direction. You can take this a lot further. Basically what you have is a sound source and a sound emitter. Obviously a radio is a sound source, and a speaker is a sound emitter, but something like a room could be both. A radio should not know what a speaker or a room is, it should only know about emitters, and it should only send sounds to them. Based on this, a room should have a collection of emitters (which would probably be speakers), and when a room gets a sound from a radio, it would simply relay that to whatever emitters it has registered. There would also be nothing stopping you from registering speaker directly to a radio. This code should help show how you might implement all of that.

```
public class Radio
{
    private HashTable<string, EventHandler<ISound>> rooms = new ...;

    public void RegisterRoom(string room, EventHandler<ISound> onSound)
    {
        rooms[room] = onSound;
    }

    public void UnregisterRoom(string room)
    {
        rooms.Remove(room);
    }

    public void PlayRoom(string room)
    {
        EventHandler<ISound> onSound;

        if (rooms.TryGetValue(room, out onSound))
        {
            onSound(this, new BuildingSpeaker() { sound = "Test" });
        }
    }

    public void PlayAllRooms()
    {
        if (rooms.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        var speaker = new BuildingSpeaker() { sound = "Test All Rooms" };

        foreach (var room in rooms)
        {
            room.Value(this, speaker);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just saw and applied your solution.  This was simple and it also solved my problem.  I hope I don't get chastised for changing my answer to this being the problem solver.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @MIJ1974 no you won't be chastised but you can still upvote that answer if you feel like it.

Comment: I can't upvote because I don't have 15 reputation.  Can I just say both GleneBob and C Bauer where extremely helpful,..Thank you guys.

Comment: @mij no one will be upset. I just provided a design pattern per the op. Design patterns are frequently more complex because they provide an answer to a general problem rather than one 'baked in' to existing code. Where my answer could be put pretty much anywhere and work, this code is 'baked into' your implementation and had to be rewritten if you want to use it elsewhere.

Comment: you are very correct.  Thank you for making me realize this.